# How do I print the contents of a register in x86 assembly to the console? I'm running Linux

Tags: assembly, x86

I know how to print a string, but the documentation on printing integers is surprisingly scarce. I'm not even sure if my question is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you can link against the C library, you could call the `printf` function. On most x86 systems, variadic functions use the `cdecl` calling convention - arguments are pushed on the stack from right to left (so, first the register value, then the string containing `%d`), and you have to clean up the stack (add to `%esp`) after the call.

For more details please specify what system you're on (and if you can't link against the C library, you'll need to generate a string by hand to convert it into whatever base you want to print in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using printf (either syscall or int $0x80), you would have to look up the gcc varargs specification. What you would want to do is insert a %i somewhere in the string and pass the register as the first vararg argument.

I don't know off the top of my head how varargs are handled in syscalls, but it would be much easier to just make a C wrapper function to print the number and link it in with the assembly program.