# How to print a register to the console x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an array of hexa words and I want to print it to the console.

```
.data
data dw 1234H, 5678H, 9191H

.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov si, offset data 
mov cx, 4

again:
mov ax, [si] ; store the value in ax
inc si       ; increment the pointer
inc si
dec cx
jnz again
```

I want to print the value of the register ax every time in this loop.

Comment: Using a series of masks and right shifts into the lower byte of the register you can isolate the minimal bits needed to form a number. Once you have that it is a matter of adding the ascii "0" to get the printable character. You can spit those one at a time or cache them for the full string.

Comment: Try using a library like [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/) or [Irvine32](http://kipirvine.com/asm/examples/index.htm). For 16-bit there surely are other libs.

Comment: In the `Related` section (to your right) do [**Print Register in Assembly x86**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621780/print-register-in-assembly-x86?rq=1) or [**How do I print the contents of a register in x86 assembly to the console? I'm running Linux**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697561/how-do-i-print-the-contents-of-a-register-in-x86-assembly-to-the-console-im-ru?rq=1) help?

Comment: With only **3** items in the list, you definitively should not be using a counter of **4**!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it (tested on EMU8086) :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
array    dw 1234H, 5678H, 9191H, 7A40H
one_char db 'x'             ;USED TO STORE ONE HEX VALUE.
two_char db 'xx',13,10,'$'  ;TWO HEX VALUES TO DISPLAY.

.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov si, offset array
mov cx, 4

again:
mov ax, [si] ; store the value in ax
;AX = AH AL.
  ;DISPLAY AH.
    push ax          ;PRESERVE CURRENT HEX NUMBER.
    mov one_char, ah ;TWO HEX VALUES OF THE FIRST BYTE.
    call separate_two_digits ;SEPARATE THE TWO HEX.
    ;DISPLAY THE TWO DIGITS.
      mov dx, offset two_char
      mov ah, 9
      int 21h
  ;DISPLAY AL.
    pop ax           ;RESTORE AX.
    mov one_char, al ;TWO HEX VALUES OF THE SECOND BYTE.
    call separate_two_digits ;SEPARATE THE TWO HEX.
    ;DISPLAY THE TWO DIGITS.
      mov dx, offset two_char
      mov ah, 9
      int 21h
inc si       ; increment the pointer
inc si
dec cx
jnz again

;WAIT FOR KEYPRESS.
mov ah, 0
int 16h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

;--------------------------------------------------                                                  
;ONE_CHAR CONTAINS TWO HEX VALUES: FIRST HEX IN THE
;4 UPPER BITS, THE SECOND HEX IN THE LOWER 4 BITS.

separate_two_digits proc
    mov  di, offset two_char
;4 UPPER BITS OF THE CHAR.
    mov  al, one_char
    shr  al, 4
    call convert2char
    mov  [ di ], al
;4 LOWER BITS OF THE CHAR.
    mov  al, one_char
    and  al, 00001111b
    call convert2char 
    inc  di
    mov  [ di ], al

    ret
separate_two_digits endp      


;--------------------------------------------------                                                  
;CONVERT FROM HEX TO ASCII CHARACTER.

convert2char proc
    cmp al, 9
    jbe digit      ;IF AL <= 9 : IT'S A DIGIT.
;UPPERCASE LETTER.
    add al, 55     ;HEX LETTER TO ASCII.
    jmp finale
digit:
    add al, 48     ;HEX DIGIT TO ASCII.

finale:        
    ret
convert2char endp
```

Comment: Very confusing your *one_char* variable since it does not contain a char. It would better be called *one_byte*.